# is there any drand48() equivalent in python or a wrapper to it?

Tags: python, random

I am converting some c code to python. I am wondering that is there any drand48() equivalent in python(exactly the same!) or a wrapper to it?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You are looking for `random.random`.

```
>>> import random
>>> help(random)
>>> random.random()
0.8423026866867628
```

It does not use the same generator as `drand48`.  The `drand48` family uses a 48-bit linear congruential generator, whereas the Python random module uses the superior Mersenne Twister algorithm.

If you want the *exact same* output as `drand48`, you can implement it in Python.

```
# Uncomment the next line if using Python 2.x...
# from __future__ import division
class Rand48(object):
    def __init__(self, seed):
        self.n = seed
    def seed(self, seed):
        self.n = seed
    def srand(self, seed):
        self.n = (seed << 16) + 0x330e
    def next(self):
        self.n = (25214903917 * self.n + 11) & (2**48 - 1)
        return self.n
    def drand(self):
        return self.next() / 2**48
    def lrand(self):
        return self.next() >> 17
    def mrand(self):
        n = self.next() >> 16
        if n & (1 << 31):
            n -= 1 << 32
        return n
```

However, the output will be significantly inferior to Python's standard random number generator.  The `rand48` family of functions were declared obsolete in 1989 by SVID 3.

Comment: I am not sure if output is the same as drand48()... So this is why I asked the question...

Comment: Its output will be different because it uses a different algorithm for generating the numbers.  However, both functions approximate a uniform(0,1) distribution.

Comment: yeah i got the idea... but still interested in drand48()

Comment: @Shan: So you need to exactly reproduce the sequence of numbers produced by `drand48` for a given seed?

Comment: @ Dietrich, yes i exactly need to reproduce rand48()

Comment: How did you figure out exactly how to represent these? I went through the man and [https://code.woboq.org/userspace/glibc/stdlib/jrand48_r.c.html#__jrand48_r] source code but seems pretty hard to just translate.

Comment: @Akaisteph7: It’s been about 10 years so I don’t remember! The glibc code takes a bit of time to get used to, but I think I actually implemented this from the man page, which specifies the exact algorithm.

Comment: I have verified that this implementation exactly matches the C implementation on Python 3.8.2. Thanks!